# Table of Contents Inside Section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I would like to add a table of contents inside a `section` environment to make a TOC made up of subsections, subsubsections and etc.
One slight difficutly is that I am not using an `article class` document; its a customized one.
I would use the article class if necessary.
I would like something along the lines of:

```
\section{Section 1}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{Sub1}
\subsection{Sub2}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the TOC inside the section should only display the contents of that particular section (and subsections), but not that of other sections?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want.

Comment: perhaps `\usepackage{etoc}` and then use `\localtableofcontents` assuming your customized class hasn't its own handling of `.toc` file. Perhaps you will need `\etocsetocstyle{}{}` to not have a too big `Contents` printed.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @jfbu. Your method worked for me. Here is my scrap code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section 1}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{Sub1}
\subsection{Sub2}

\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{Sub1}
\subsection{Sub2}


\end{document}
```